# How to set permissions in azure AD for spring boot api?

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2, azure-webapps

1. How I can set custom method-level permissions in azure Ad and pass that via access token. I found it is available for roles only. Is any way to set it in azure?

   Spring boot Controller.

```
  @GetMapping("/file1")
  @ResponseBody
  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('access_1')")
  fun file1(): String {
    return "File read success."
  }
```

Comment: Please look into  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps.

Comment: Thanks Allen, But this url having only roles and  group. Its not sufficent for large scale application. After checking a lot. Microsoft Azure AD  method-level permissions to api is not available right now. May be in the future its avialable. Finally I planned to movie with Keycloak+AzureAD.

Comment: OK. So you have reached a conclusion, right? If you are willing to add an answer, we would appreciate it.